# create geom_segment() per factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw horizontal line segments at the `y` mean of each `x` factor.

Expected output something like this:

[image]

My approach is to use `geom_segment()`, but I'm getting an error about the length of the aes.

> Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2): y

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)      

# data
df <- structure(list(d = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), y = c(6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6), z = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

# group means
means <- df %>% 
  group_by(d) %>% 
  summarize(y = mean(y)) %>%
  mutate(d = factor(d)) %>%
  mutate(x = case_when(
    d==0 ~ 0.5,
    TRUE ~ 1.5
  )) %>%
  mutate(xend = case_when(
    d==0 ~ 1.5,
    TRUE ~ 2.5 
  )) %>%
  mutate(yend = y)

# plot
df %>%
  mutate(z = factor(z),
         d = factor(d)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=d, 
             y=y, 
             color=z)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(seed = 42),
             alpha = 0.7) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "#CC0200")) +
  new_scale_colour() +
  geom_segment(data = means, 
               aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend, 
                   colour = d)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#e69138", "#1f9ac9")) +
  guides(color = "none")
```

Comment: Typo? I wonder if `y = mean` should instead be `y = y` (since your `means` dataset has names `c("d", "y", "x", "xend", "yend")`, none of which are `"mean"`). This returns an error for me (since `mean` here is a _function_), perhaps you have an object named `mean` from past calculations?) Fixing that, I see factored scatter plot with two lines.

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans that is definitely a typo. Fixed above. A mistake moving from use case to toy example. Fixing it though gives me  an error about continuous vs discrete values. I'm troubleshooting though...

Comment: I get points and the line segments if I turn off `new_scale_colour()`, but this gives me the wrong colors. For a complicated reason, I am using `new_scale_colour()` to have a different set of colors for points vs segments.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue but got a different error `object 'z' not found`. After fixing this by moving `color=z` to geom_point() your code works fine and gives me the expected result.

Comment: I'll check back in a few days and add this corrected answer if you have not done so already. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stefan's solution works: move `color=z` to `geom_point()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)      

# data
df <- structure(list(d = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), y = c(6, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6), z = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

# group means
means <- df %>% 
  group_by(d) %>% 
  summarize(y = mean(y)) %>%
  mutate(d = factor(d)) %>%
  mutate(x = case_when(
    d==0 ~ 0.5,
    TRUE ~ 1.5
  )) %>%
  mutate(xend = case_when(
    d==0 ~ 1.5,
    TRUE ~ 2.5 
  )) %>%
  mutate(yend = y)

# plot
df %>%
  mutate(z = factor(z),
         d = factor(d)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=d, 
             y=y)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(seed = 42),
             alpha = 0.7, aes(color=z)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "#CC0200")) +
  new_scale_colour() +
  geom_segment(data = means, 
               aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend, 
                   colour = d)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#e69138", "#1f9ac9")) +
  guides(color = "none")
```